# Alternative to adobe flash on centos 7?

Tags: centos, adobe-flash

Am unable to play content from sites like "hbogo.com" on my centos machine, as it warns me of having outdated flash player. As adobe is not supporting linux updates anymore, can you suggest me alternatives to flash player.

I came across pepper flash plugin, but it seems its only available for ubuntu.
Is there anything equivalent for centos as well ?

Please enlighten me :), appreciate the help.

Comment: How about using Google Chrome?

Answer (score 1):

Currently Adobe has stopped releasing any updates for the Linux version of flash. Adobe is moving to a new plug-in framework that Google Chrome uses that is supposed to make the plug-ins cross platform compatible. The idea being that they would not have to make as many or any changes to make it cross platform compatible.

If you download and install Google Chrome it comes with the latest version of flash built in but you have to get it from the Google website.

[Google Chrome](http://www.google.com/chrome/index.html?hl=en&brand=CHMA&utm_campaign=en&utm_source=en-ha-na-us-sk&utm_medium=ha&utm_term=chrome)